# Send a MySQL query when pressing checkbox with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to send an update query when a checkbox is pressed, using AJAX. How can I do this?

#### HTML imports:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/checkbox.js"></script>
```

#### HTML checkbox:

```
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="" class="checkbox">  Ingevoerd<br>
</td>
```

(Yes my checkbox is in a table, I don't know if this has to be in a form.)

#### JavaScript code:

```
$(".checkbox").change(function() {
    window.alert(5 + 6);
    $.ajax({
        url: '../ingevoerd.php'
    });
});
```

(the `window.alert` is not triggered when I press the checkbox)

#### PHP code:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE table SET temp=0 where id = 1');
$stmt->execute();
var_dump('test');
```

Comment: Have you tried `$(".checkbox").click()` ?

Comment: Use `.click` instead of `.change` and before do the ajax call verify if the checkbox is `checked` or not

Comment: copied the .change from another question, tried .click but didn't help

Comment: it display some error? warning? something?

Comment: the answer below, helped me, the alert succeeds, the query hasen't succeded yet, thanks for the info!

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery instead of $

Answer (score 2):

I guess your javascript code runs before your html exists, so when your browser is trying to find `$(".checkbox")`, there aren't any elements with the `checkbox` class yet.

You should have the code running only after the document is ready:

```
$(function() {
    $(".checkbox").change(function() {
        window.alert(5 + 6);
        $.ajax({
            url: '../ingevoerd.php'
        });
    });
});
```

In the next example you can see that **nothing will happen** (because the javascript code exists before the elements are available in the DOM):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('#d1').css('background', 'red');
</script>
<div id="d1">some block</div>
```

Same example, but wait for the DOM to be ready (this example **will work** as expected):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#d1').css('background', 'red');
  });
</script>
<div id="d1">some block</div>
```

Comment: I was just about to say that, but shouldn't he use `document.ready()` to make sure the page have finished loading? I don't know all the little tricks of Jquery.

Comment: @Matthew,  the `$(function() { ... });` is only a short way to write `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: thanks! Did not know that, now it make sense why I see some people do that.

Comment: I did have my scripts loaded before the html page was loaded, which was pretty dumb, have placed it under my footer and added document.ready (to b sure) but to no effect for the moment

Comment: @sansactions, did the `alert` work? Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: @Dekel Yes my friend, changed some things and the alert works now, thank you, i will now check if the query succeeded!

Comment: @Dekel the query hasn't succeeded, could this have something to do with old imports?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "old imports".

Comment: BTW, you have a table in your database with the name `table`?! It's a big NO NO

Comment: @Dekel i meant that i am not sure if my imports are correct to use ajax the way i want and no i don't have a table with table, it was just for question sake

Comment: Well, I really don't know where the problem is. You should check the logs to see if you have problem in you PHP or in you Query.  Currently your javascript works as expected.

Comment: idk if the ajax works but the on click event of the checkbox works, thnx for that, i will look a bit further

Comment: @Dekel i forgot some imports, i ficked it now, thnx for the help

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark the answer as correct (and a vote up will also be appreciated).